# Eclipse p2 mirrorApplication artifact filtering

Tags: eclipse, mirroring, p2

I am trying to mirror an update site under Windows with the following commands.

```
eclipsec -nosplash -verbose -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -writeMode clean -source http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.1/1.1.0.20120530-0009 -destination file:/C:/m2ecore
eclipsec -nosplash -verbose -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -writeMode clean -source http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.1/1.1.0.20120530-0009 -destination file:/C:/m2ecore
```

That works, but it downloads all the artifacts twice, both in canonical form and packed form. For example:

```
Mirroring: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.source,1.1.0.20120530-0009 (Descriptor: packed: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.source,1.1.0.20120530-0009)
Mirroring: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.source,1.1.0.20120530-0009 (Descriptor: canonical: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.source,1.1.0.20120530-0009)
```

**Is there a way to specify that I only want to mirror the canonical forms?**
Something like `-filter (!format=packed)`

I have noticed that there are filters in *artifacts.xml* and that the p2 application seems to support the *filter* switch, it's just poorly documented. It looks like an LDAP query but it is not being recognized from the command line.

If it's not possible to filter, how can I safely alter the local repo to remove the packed files from the metadata? Editing the XML by hand doesn't seem like a good idea.

**EDIT:** Did it the manual way. *Leaving the question open in case someone knows how to filter to avoid the unnecessary downloads*

Go to *C:\m2ecore*, unzip *artifacts.jar*, and then delete it.
Edit the *properties* section in *artifacts.xml*

```
Remove the line <property name='publishPackFilesAsSiblings' value='true'/>
Adjust the properties size parameter (e.g: from 3 to 2)
```

Edit the *mappings* section in *artifacts.xml*

```
Remove the line <rule filter='(&amp; (classifier=osgi.bundle) (format=packed))' output='${repoUrl}/plugins/${id}_${version}.jar.pack.gz'/>
Remove the line <rule filter='(&amp; (classifier=org.eclipse.update.feature) (format=packed))' output='${repoUrl}/features/${id}_${version}.jar.pack.gz'/>
Adjust the mappings size parameter (e.g.: from 5 to 3)
```

Remove all packed artifact metadata

```
Use an editor with regex support to clear all matches of:
<artifact[\s]+[^>]*>(.(?!<[/]?artifact>))+Pack200Unpacker(.(?!<[/]?artifact>))+[\s]*</artifact>

To clear the blank lines, first regex replace with empty strings the matches of:  
^[\s]*$
and then do an extended replace from \r\n\r\n to \r\n

Modify the total artifacts count by searching for matches of:
<artifact[\s]+[^>]*>
```

Zip *artifacts.xml* into *artifacts.zip* and rename it to *artifacts.jar*
Delete all _*.pack.gz_ files from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Standalone mirror application has limited capabilities, you can use [p2 ant task](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_repositorytasks.htm) to get what you want.